# Find a inner text between 2 symbols and replace inner text using regular expressions in php

Tags: php, regex

I've been googling and trying to get this myself but I can't and  only get a headache. 
I have this string:

```
"estamos en el registro {id} cuyo contenido es {contenido} por lo que veremos su {foto}"
```

I need replace the {value} with $value getting a string like this

```
"estamos en el registro $id cuyo contenido es $contenido por lo que veremos su $foto"
```

It is posibble using regular expressions in PHP

Thanks in advance for any answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
$replaced = preg_replace('~{([^}]*)}~', '$$1', $yourstring);
```

On [the demo](http://regex101.com/r/kP8iJ5), see the substitutions at the bottom.

- `{` matches the opening brace
- `}` matches the closing brace
- In `([^}]*)`, the parentheses captures to Group 1 `[^}]*`... `[^}]` is a negative character class that means one char that is not a closing brace, and the `*` quantifier means zero or more times
- `$$1` replaces the match with a literal `$` and the content of capture Group (`$1`)

Comment: great this works fine, an the demo site is very usefull I did not know a web for regular expression thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible, you can use the [`preg_replace()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) function to perform this task.

If the curly braces are always balanced, you can use the following.

```
$text = preg_replace('/{(.*?)}/', '$$1', $text);
```

[**Working Demo**](https://eval.in/166943)